What is the best way to model the impact of multiple therapies/diagnostic tests on healthcare resource utilization and costs pre- and post-treatment?
I have a methods question that I'm hoping this group might be able to answer. I'm planning an causal inference analysis in R where we want to see how the use of Diagnostic Test 1 rather than Diagnostic Tests 2, 3, 4, etc. will impact healthcare resource utilization and cost. HCRU would be number of inpatient, outpatient, emergency visits; cost would be cost of those visits. These are measured twice: in the 12 months before (and including) the index date and in the 12 months after (and excluding) the index date.
Since this is a causal inference problem, I'm thinking of going back to one of my favorite econometric methods, difference-in-differences. Because our diagnostic test groups are imbalanced, I'm planning to do inverse probability treatment weighting (IPTW) with the difference-in-differences (as in Abadie 2005). This method is based on ordinary least squares, but I'm wondering if there's a GLM equivalent that would allow you to specify distributions - e.g., in a GLM, costs should take a gamma distribution with a log-link. Additionally, I need to consider the fact that patients may get another diagnostic test, either of the same type or a different type, during the follow-up period.
The code below is what I'd use for IPWDID (based on Pedro Sant'Anna's DRDID package).
ipwdid( yname="post_index_cost", tname="pre_post_flag", idname="patient_id", dname="dxtest", xformla = ~ age + gender + ... + treatment + pre_index_cost, data=treatment_hcru_costs, panel = TRUE, normalized = TRUE, weightsname = NULL, boot = FALSE, boot.type = "weighted", nboot = 999, inffunc = TRUE )
This approach (I think) doesn't allow you to specify a distribution, and it also doesn't account for cohort switching in the follow-up period. I'm wondering if there are any alternatives besides running a GLM on my IPTW data with an interaction term (dxtest*pre_post_flag). Any advice would be enormously appreciated!
